# Android Virtual Device Creation failed to parse properties

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When I try to create a new AVD in Eclipse, I have the image installed but that's not the problem. I get the message

```
failed to parse properties from /home/kevin/.android/avd/icecream.avd/config.ini
```

when I look at the machine.

Comment: Can you show the file config.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this while trying to create a Nexus 5 AVD. Post creation, the folder didn't have a config.ini

I just created another configuration of avd & worked on the first try. Go figure.

Answer (score 7):

step-1:go to window-> avd manager
step-2:select installed avd and click edit
step-3:click EditAVD Button in bottom

Then your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `icecream.ini` (from `/home/kevin/.android/avd/`) should be edited: possibly you need to change path attribute - it should reffer to `icecream.avd` folder location.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough free space.