# ERROR: Failed to parse properties from config.ini; AVD ERROR

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I've problem while loading emulator in android studio 3.1.

When I click *run emulator* it says

```
Error: Failed to parse properties from C:\Users\John\.android\avd\3.7_WVGA_Nexus_One_API_22.avd\config.ini
```

When I went to the `avd\3.7_WVGA_Nexus_One_API_22.avd` there was no `config.ini` file in it but in `.android\avd` folder there was a `3.7_WVGA_Nexus_One_API_22.ini` file.

I thought this was the file the avd was searching for, so renamed it to `config.ini` and pasted in `avd\3.7_WVGA_Nexus_One_API_22.avd` folder and then I restarted android studio. But once again it was showing the same error!

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I solved it using this solution : [Android Virtual Device Creation failed to parse properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392648/android-virtual-device-creation-failed-to-parse-properties)

"step-1:go to window-> avd manager step-2:select installed avd and click edit step-3:click EditAVD Button in bottom

Then your problem is solved."

Comment: Thanks for answering even after so many years... I don't even know if this will work as I bought a new PC and this PC doesn't show this error Thanks for answering once again.... :)

Comment: Btw what I think was causing the problem in that PC was low memory... as I had only 4 gigs of slow DDR2 RAM...  Now I have more than enough memory to run android studio, this error never showed up.