# Can I share common AVD folder across different (Android Studio) users on same Windows machine?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am installing Android Studio in a school lab.  I want to have one virtual device (emulator) available to students using the software.  There will be different students using the same PCs, which have limited primary SSD drives and spacious secondary mechanical drives (all running Windows 10).

**The problem:** When I create one virtual device, Android Studio creates the following folder:

> c:\users"whatever_user_name".android\avd"whatever_name_of_device"

It puts all necessary files there, quickly making this folder a few GB in size.  It also creates a similarly named .ini file in that same avd folder.  After researching this, I could move the avd folder to a separate location, where all users can have read/write access (using my D drives), in the hope of sharing the necessary big image files among different users (and de-cluttering their c\users... profile).  I changed the .ini file to point to the new location. I gave read/write access to all domain users in that location.

This works successfully (emulator runs properly with new, custom avd location) **but only for the initial user who "created" the Virtual Device**.  Whenever I try to configure the second user's Android Studio to point into the same publicly available avd folder, the emulator hangs with an error `"Failed to parse properties from custom_location_of_avd/config.ini"`

There is no config.ini in that folder.  I researched this error but [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392648/android-virtual-device-creation-failed-to-parse-properties/17813888#17813888) are quite old and/or irrelevant.

I can solve it by creating a new virtual device and that works, but that basically means a few GB per user every time ...

***TL;DR - In a few words .. Is there a way to share common AVD resources among different users using Android Studio in the same Windows machine?***

Comment: In case of Linux it should be possible by putting all ```AVDs``` into the *shared volume* and adding all users *to the new group* which has ```read & execute permissions``` on that ```AVDs``` and ```Android Studio```. I haven't checked it, but in theory it should work. Windows system should allow to do similar use case.